# parsing IST date format

Tags: java, date, talend

I'm using Talend 5.5.

In my project there is a part which I need to convert dates in IST format to this format: "yyyy-MM-dd" .

For example:

> wed 0ct 08 00:00:00 IST 2014

TO

> 2014-10-08

I placed this code in a tMap component:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
 .parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
 .format(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(row4.Date)))
```

row4.date is the date that i want to convert and is equal to "wed 0ct 08 00:00:00 IST 2014" for example.

and I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1380)
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:355)
```

What is the reason for the exception?

Comment: Are you sure that `row4.Date` is the value you expected? It looks like te value is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if(null!=row4 && null!=row4.Date)//use null check    
     new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
     .parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
     .format(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(row4.Date)))
```

One way to handle Null pointer is to do null checks and another and better way is to use try catch blocks so that it does not interrupt your code execution.

Comment: This will give you a compiler error. You have to make the null check at start of your snipped.

Comment: or row4 itself is null then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(date);
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Comment: This will not help the OP. Becase you format the actual date and not `row4.Date`

Comment: "row4.date is equal to "wed 0ct 08 00:00:00 IST 2014" for example." which is nothing but a Date object with toString representation from user so why do you think it wont work? Btw above example was just a usage of how to get date from "wed 0ct 08 00:00:00 IST 2014" format to "2014-10-08". Hope this helps.

Comment: But OP knows how he has to fomat the date. He gat an error parsing the date.

Comment: But see his code, is that what we should recommend?

Comment: No. But if `row4.Date` is not `null` and it has the correct format it should work. For critic you should write a comment.

Comment: Defo i agree with you that it could be row4.date that is passed as null and hence NPE.